# laravel private chat application

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Hello i'm a new developer and in my laravel project i have implemented a real time group chat  that uses ajax but now i need a real time chat between users in ajax i have tried many things but none have worken   it would be very helpful if you could help me or if could send me a link to a good tutorial

Here's the index of my group chat :

```
@extends('admin.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style ="padding-top:40px;">
            <h3 class="text-center">Welcome {{Auth::user()->FullName}}</h3>
            <br/><br/>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>Users online</p>
                    @foreach($users as $user)
                        @if($user->isOnline())
                            <li>{{$user->FullName}}</li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Recent Chat
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="media-list" id="message">

                            @foreach($messages as $message )
                                <li class="media">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <div class="media">

                                            <div class="media-body" >
                                                {{$message->message}}
                                                <br/>
                                               <bold> <small class="text-muted">{{$message->from_name}} |{{$message->created_at}}
                                                   </small></bold>
                                                <hr>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>


                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                        <div>
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"/>
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <input type="hidden" name="from_name" value="{{Auth::user()->FullName}}">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
                                </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/admin/plugins/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
        });
        function realTime() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'/chat/get',
                data:{
                    '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#message').replaceWith(' <ul class="media-list" id="message"></ul>');
                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                        $('#message').append(' <li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div class="media-body">'+data[i].message+'<br/><small class="text-muted">'+data[i].from_name+'|'+ data[i].created_at+'</small><hr/></div></div></div></li>')
                    }
                },
            });
            setTimeout(realTime, 2000);
        }
        $(document).on('click','#send', function (){
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'/chat/send',
                data:{
                    '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
                    'from_name':$('input[name=from_name]').val(),
                    'message':$('input[name=message]').val(),
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $('#message').append('  <li class="media"><div class="media-body"><div class="media"><div class="media-body">'+data.message+'<br/><small class="text-muted">'+data.from_name+'|'+ data.created_at+'</small><hr/></div></div></div></li>');
                }
            })

            $('input[name=message]').val('');
        });

    </script>

@stop
```

here are the routes of my group chat:

```
Route::get('/chat', 'Chat\ChatController@index')->name('chat.index');
Route::post('/chat/send', 'Chat\ChatController@sendMessage' )->name('admin.chat.sendMessage');
Route::post('/chat/get', 'Chat\ChatController@getMessage' );
```

here's my controllers of the group chat:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    $users=user::all();
    $messages=message::all();
    return view('admin.chat.index',['messages'=> $messages],compact('users'));
}

public function sendMessage(Request $request){

    $send = new Message();
    $send ->from_name = $request->from_name;
    $send ->message = $request->message;
    $send->save();
    return response()->json($send);

}

public function  getMessage(){
    $message = Message::all();
    return response()->json($message);
}
```

here the migration for my gruop chat :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateMessagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('from_name');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('messages');
    }
}
```

Sorry in advance for the bad english and it would very grateful if you could help me or if you could send the link of a good tutorial

Comment: Ok, now the gremlins in SO will need the configuration of your server so they can create the virtual machine and start developing your application.

Comment: Try using [websocket](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270)

Comment: Route::post('/chat/get', 'Chat\ChatController@getMessage' );
you sure you want this as a post? I think it should be a get method as you're requesting data from server.

also can you tell us what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: no everything is fine in the group chat ,but now i want to implement a private  chat system beetwen two users like facebook

Comment: chat using ajax, prolly not a good idea ! Websockets instead!

Comment: yeah i know but that was the fastest and esaiest way to do it because i was in a time limit for that chat

Answer (score 0):

You need a live connection for that using a websocket, and you can achieve this with Laravel.

What this does is actually keep the connection between the server and the clients open and allows the server to send data to the clients, not just the other way around. Therefore you are able to send the messages to one of the people in your chat as soon as you receive them from the other participant.

That's called Broadcasting in Laravel, take a look at the documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting

Comment: i understand but i don't know how to create a chat with only two  users,and a user is free to message anyone they want